# Android app crash exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm stucking with below crash report for my android application, anyone has an idea what is the exact issue and how to get resolved.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3397)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1780)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1538)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1484)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:663)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:663)
  at android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService (WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java:91)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.b (zzg.java:9)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.a (zzg.java:72)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.onReceive (FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.java:31)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3390)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1780)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Facing issue in specific OS?

Comment: Yes, it's happening only on Android 8.0

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to start a `Service` from a background thread. From Oreo and up this is no longer supported because of [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background). There's a migration guide at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm just not able to figure out which part of my code that need to be migrated, is the issue related to firebase integration?

Comment: I would start at your implementation of the `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and make sure you're not starting a service in the `onTokenRefresh` function since some internal firebase instance id receiver is mentioned. I assume you're running the latest version of all your firebase dependencies?

Comment: Actually, I'm not starting any service inside onTokenRefresh (the method is empty), not sure if I'm using the latest version of firebase dependencies.

Comment: If you only use FCM to send notifications through the Firebase Console it's ok to leave the `onTokenRefresh` function empty. To make sure you're on the latest version go to your app module build.gradle file and make sure this version is used in the dependency block `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'`. It's possible Firebase itself was internally starting the service in versions which predate Oreo. In the error message it looks like the error is coming from a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` so just search your entire project for that.

Comment: I tried to search for WakefulBroadcastReceiver  with no hits, I found that I use old version of firebase belong to com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1, I will update to the latest version as per your advice.

Comment: And one more thing I already listed below figures in AndroidManifest file, is there any issue related to them with Android 8.0                         
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

Comment: Well that's a pretty outdated version, let's hope that was the issue. The service declaration in your manifest is good.